# Sys.Webforms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException server error 503

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003, runtime-error

I'm Referring to this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2010/10/08/steps-for-setting-up-a-custom-identity-of-an-iis-6-application-pool.aspx) as I have to write file from one server to another I'm trying to create a custom domain account on Windows server.

I have done all as told in the link however when I browse the site I get the following error:

[image]

I was refferring the following [link](http://forums.asp.net/post/1555817.aspx) for the error.

However no success yet

I get this error when I authorise my network service for the application pool

```
Access to the path '\\servername\c$\fromvini\abc.text is denied.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To been able to read the file on the remote computer you have two ways.

#### First way - both computers have the same account.

1. Both computers must have the same user name / and password
2. On the IIS server that runs the site, you place that account to run the pool of that site, do not make this account as service account, but you need to correct setup the site directory to be able to run.
3. On the remote server you let and the share connection to be able to seen by this account, but also you change the credential of the directory and the files to have permission for that account.

#### Second way - open the file with different login than the pool

1. The site is run under what ever pool use, maybe service account, we do not care.
2. Setup on the second server the user name / password that you going to use on the first one.
3. You open the share of the files, and change the file permissions for that acount.
4. You use the `Impersonate` to run under the other user the File access.

for example:

```
using ( new Impersonator( "myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword" ) )
{
      //... read the file
}
```

and one full example: http://forums.asp.net/t/1840443.aspx/1?How+to+copy+file+from+network+share+in+VB

Comment: I have already tried the first step thats why i get the error above

Comment: @vini Are you able to login from one computer to the other manual ? I mean you, when you are on the computer, can you use that name/pass to see the other computers files ?